# Can you trash your own keeper?

Tags: fluxx

Say you have 2 keepers (*Love* and *War* for example), and the current rules allow you to play 2 cards.  In your hand you have *All you Need is Love* (goal) and *Trash a Keeper* (action).

Can you trash your own *War* keeper, play the appropriate goal, and win?  *Trash a Keeper* says you can trash any keeper; to me that includes your own.

Similar situations include when the goal is already played, and various configurations involving *Peace (no War)* and *The Brain (no TV)*.

This came up in my hand in a game with my daughter the other night, I house-ruled against myself and she went on to win.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, any unless the card specifies who it can be played on you are free to play it on anyone including yourself. You are free to trash your own keeper and play the other card allowing you to win.

Comment: Minor quibble - actions aren't played on anyone - you play it to the center of the table, and the follow the instructions